# How to add a apache nifi flowfile into a httpresponse

Tags: httpresponse, apache-nifi

I have a working webservice with nifi where I get a httprequest and can respone to it. For test I use ReplaceText to add a specifi content to the response. This works, but  my goal is to add a flowfile (or the value of it) as the content of the httpresponse.

The usecase is, that I can send information (from Kafka, HDFS, ...) as a response of an httprequest (REST Webservice).

I was searching and testing for a solution, but nothing works. Is it possbile with a standard processor of Apache NiFi (Hortonworks HDF)?

best regards
n3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to send the contents of any flow file back through HandleHttpResponse. For example, to create a web service that returns files from HDFS you should be able to do something like:

HandleHttpRequest -> FetchHDFS -> HandleHttpResponse

You may need to do some more stuff before FetchHDFS, to manipulate the data, but that would be the general approach. The key is that you need a processor that accepts incoming flow files, so for Kafka you could easily do the same thing with PutKafka, but not GetKafka because it doesn't accept an incoming flow file.

This GitHub repo has an example of a web service that retrieves a file from local disk: https://github.com/bbende/nifi-streaming-examples

See the first image where it says "Handle Request for Log Levels".

Comment: thank you for the answer. My problem is, that I want to use Kafka and as you wrote, it is not possible, because GetKafka doesn't accept incoming flow files. You mention to use PutKafka instead, but how? I'm a little bit confused :?

Comment: For Kafka, I was saying that you could make a web service that acted as a Kafka producer by having a POST request go to HandleHttpRequest -> PutKafka -> HandleHttpResponse, but currently there isn't a way to make a web service that would act as a Kafka consumer. We would have to see if it made sense to allow incoming flow files to GetKafka, currently it is a source processor.

Comment: So there is no option to send something from Kafka based on an HttpRequest? Hm... should it work with MergeContent or ReplaceText? I tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Currently there is not due to the fact that GetKafka does not support incoming connections. You can only use HandleHttpRequest/Response with a processor than receive a flow file and overwrite the contents with something to send back. I would encourage you to shoot a note to the NiFi dev community to start a discussion about how to support this for GetKafka https://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html